# is DQL better than object syntax using Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get a hang of doctrine and have had a chance to look at some DQL stuff and have been able to do some simple inserts like:

```
 function insert_user($username,$email,$password) 
        {
$user = new User();
$user->setUsername($username);
$user->setEmail($email);
$user->setPassword(md5($password));

    try {
            //save to database
            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush();
        }
        catch(Exception $err){

            die($err->getMessage());

            return false;
        }
        return true;
        }
```

However I am still challenged in terms of how to do a routine like username/password authentication. For instance I have:

```
    function validate_user($username,$password) 
            {
$query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT u from User u WHERE u.username = :name AND u.username = :name2');
$query->setParameters(array(
    'name' => $username,
    'name2' => $password,
));
$users = $query->getResult(); // array of user objects
            }
```

Here is my entity class:

```
<?php



use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @Table(name="user")
 * @Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $username
     *
     * @Column(name="username", type="string", length=300, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @Column(name="email", type="string", length=300, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string $password
     *
     * @Column(name="password", type="string", length=300, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }
}
```

I guess I can figure it out in DQL however not too sure how to do it using object syntax.

I hope my question makes sense as I am just trying to get familiar.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [doctrine 2 documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#types-of-dql-queries) you can't INSERT using DQL:

> DQL as a query language has SELECT, UPDATE and DELETE constructs that
> map to their corresponding SQL statement types. **INSERT statements are
> not allowed in DQL**, because entities and their relations have to be
> introduced into the persistence context   through
> EntityManager#persist() to ensure consistency of your object model.

However i agree with you that inserting using DQL could help us do some tasks including many-to many relationships a lot easier in some cases.